# Mercurial: Merge a single change into an unnamed branch

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have a project that sometimes branches out for a time. I don't use named branches.

I then use Merge in order to pull the branch back together. So given a tree like this

```
o Change 3 on Branch B
║
o Change 2 on Branch B
║
║ o Change 1 on Branch A
╠═╝
o Source
```

I can merge in Change 2 like this

```
o Merge of change 2 into Branch A
╠═╗
║ ║ o Change 3 on Branch B
║ ╠═╝
║ o Change 2 on Branch B
║ ║
o ║ Change 1 on Branch A
╠═╝
o Source
```

But **what would be the recommended way to copy/merge Change 3** into Branch A, without merging its parents? (specifically, **without merging Change 2**)

The way I do it now is to manually compare the difference between 2 and 3, and repeat the changes in a number 4.

Comment: See: [Graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft)

Answer (score 1):

Because you already merged `Change 2 on Branch B` and `Change 3 on Branch B` is **single unmerged cset in branch**, you can just merge branches again

In case of "*merge only some* unmerged changeset from branch to branch" you have to use graft, as mentioned (in fresh Mercurial) or transplant